# What grade of plywood should we use as subfloor under VCT tile?

Tags: subfloor, plywood, vinyl-flooring

What is the preferred grade of plywood we should use as a subfloor underneath commercial-grade Vinyl Composition Tile (VCT) tile (not vinyl peel & stick tile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically any plywood will do.  If I were doing it I would go with 3/4 inch.  The key to a vinyl install install isn't the quality or depth of the subfloor but how flat it is.  Any divots or seams bigger than 1/8" could have issues in the future and need to be filled.

Comment: We will be using 3/4", but were told to get plywood with a  completely smooth finish, without filled knots.  Is this necessary, or will the filled knots be problematic in the future?